# How can I access the first two elements of a list without using recursion?

Tags: prolog

How can I access the first two elements of a list without using recursion ?

for example: if I have a list (X1,X2,X3,X4,X5)

And I want to do X1*X2 +X2*X3 + X3*X4 +X4*X5 + X5*X1

is that correct?

```
List([X|Y,List],Sum):-  ListAcc([Y,List],0,Sum).
ListAcc([X|Y,List],Acc,Sum):-NewAcc is Acc+ X*Y, ListAcc([Y,List],NewAcc,Sum).
ListAcc[[],Acc,Sum).
```

is that legal ?
(and I wasn't sure how to add the sum of (X5*X1)

Comment: `[X|Y,List]` is not proper syntax. You want `[X,Y|List]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes this special, is that you have to remember the first item, to multiply it with the last.

```
ListAcc([H1, H2|T], Sum) :-
    # We need to remember the first element.
    ListAcc([H1,H2|T], Sum, H1).

ListAcc([Hz|[]], Sum, H1) :-
    # We reached the last element, 
    # so we multiply with the first element which we rememebered.
    Sum is H1 * Hz.

ListAcc([H1, H2|T], Sum, H) :-
    # We calculate the listacc of the rest...
    ListAcc([H2|T], Sum1, H),
    # ...then we add the product of the first and the second element.
    Sum is Sum1 + H1 * H2.
```

Comment: What is X1? can you run a small example ?

Comment: @Shiran I'm sorry, I messed up. What I meant was that the first element should be 'remembered' to be multiplied with the last element.

Comment: @Shiran It was overly complex, too. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3):

To access the first two elements of a list unify like this

```
?- L = [a,b,c,d], [X,Y|Rest] = L.
L = [a, b, c, d],
X = a,
Y = b,
Rest = [c, d].
```

Regarding your second question:

- Prolog predicates must start with a non-capital letter: `List` should be `list`.
- In the last rule, the solution has to unify with the accumulator: `listAcc([],Sum, Sum)`, but I think that in this case you should have a special rule for a list with a single element.
- You need to pass the first element of the list until you get to the last one. Maybe, your predicate should look like this: `listAcc(+NumbersLeft, +First, +Acc, -Sum)`.
- Be careful for a particular case: a list with a single element. The sum for the list `[X1]` should be 0 or `X1*X1`?

Comment: so the head should include the elements? and not the tail ?

Comment: Yes, a list unifies with `[X1, X2, ... Xn | Tail]`, but only if it has at least `n` elements.

Comment: @Shiran by definition the head and tail are separate. And you can match however many head elements you wish. If you say, `[a,b,c,d] = [H|T]` it will yield, `H = a` and `T = [b,c,d]`. If you say, `[a,b,c,d] = [X,Y|T]` it will yield, `X = a`, `Y = b`, and `T = [c,d]`. If you say, `[a,b,c,d] = [X,Y,Z,W|T]` it will say `X=a`, `Y=b`, `Z=c`, `W=d` and `T=[]`. And finally, if you say, `[a,b,c,d] = [X,Y,Z,W,B]` or `[a,b,c,d] = [X,Y,Z,W,B|T]` it will fail because there aren't enough elements in `[a,b,c,d]`.